# Aws unable to delete role in a organization created account

Tags: amazon-web-services

we have an aws 'test' account created by our aws Organization.
i was creating some roles for testing purposes, but i'm totally unable to delete them, even with the root account. The error is:

User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root is not authorized to perform: iam:DeleteRole on resource: role test with an explicit deny.

i have no policy attached on the rule, everything seems fine.

Btw, the same scenario works correctly on the organization master account, i can delete roles there.

Anyone can help?

Thanks
D.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that either there is a policy attached to `user` (or to a `group` to which user belongs) which is denying this action.

You can also confirm if this `role` is assigned to some instance profile or to another user/group.

Comment: tested it with a root account and with a iam account with `AdministratorAccess`, no luck

`list-instance-profiles-for-role`, `list-role-policies` and `list-attached-role-policies` return empty values.

even the  aws `iam get-role` command gives the AccessDenied error, which to me is very strange